# Compare date fields into two datatables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable, compare

I have two DataTables and I need to compare three columns of them.

The first DataTable is created in vb.net with this code:

```
Using DT1 As DataTable = New DataTable
    With DT1
        .Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
        .Columns.Add("In_Date", GetType(Date))
        .Columns.Add("Out_Date", GetType(Date))
        .Columns.Add("RowNum", GetType(Byte))
        .PrimaryKey = {.Columns("RowNum")}
    End With
'...
```

The other DataTable is created by querying a MySql Database and so all fields are strings.

The query returns an empty string (`''`) when a date field is `NULL`:

```
SELECT IdEv, Type, 
       IF(In_Date='0000-00-00' 
          OR In_Date IS NULL,'',DATE_FORMAT(In_Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
          ) AS In_Date, 
       IF(Out_Date='0000-00-00' 
          OR Out_Date IS NULL,'',DATE_FORMAT(Out_Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
          ) AS Out_Date,
       IdLi 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE IdLi = 1
```

After many failed attempts, now I'm doing this way:

To make fields comparable I run a loop to change all empty strings into date fields to `DBNull.Value` :

```
For x As Short = 0 To DT2.Rows.Count - 1
    If DT2.Rows(x)("In_Date") = "" Then DT2.Rows(x)("In_Date") = DBNull.Value
    If DT2.Rows(x)("Out_Date") = "" Then DT2.Rows(x)("Out_Date") = DBNull.Value
Next
```

then I compare with this code:

```
If Not DT1.Rows(x)("Type").Equals(DT2.Rows(x)("Type")) OrElse Not _
   If(IsDBNull(DT1.Rows(x)("In_Date")), 0, CDate(DT1.Rows(x)("In_Date"))).Equals(If(IsDBNull(DT2.Rows(x)("In_Date")), 0, CDate(DT2.Rows(x)("In_Date")))) OrElse _
   If(IsDBNull(DT1.Rows(x)("Out_Date")), 0, CDate(DT1.Rows(x)("Out_Date"))).Equals(If(IsDBNull(DT2.Rows(x)("Out_Date")), 0, CDate(DT2.Rows(x)("Out_Date")))) Then
```

I made some test and it seems to work but I'm afraid of wrong results.

Can you say me if my code does its work and gives me right answers?

Comment: By the code you post, this seems to work well.

Comment: I do not see the reason, why the result of 'querying a MySql Database' has to result in a table where only strings are ...

Comment: @nabuchodonossor It isn't my choice! I use `Using ds As DataSet = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CnStr, SqlStr)` to get a dataset and all the fields of the DataTable containing the query result are of type `String`. If there is a way to get a DataTable having fields of type `Date` I'll be happy to use it

Comment: If the MySQL db Table has columns that are Date, they will be date in the Datatable.  There is nothing broken in MySQL that dates are converted to string

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your tip. I changed my query (and also my connection string) and now I get a `System.DateTime` Type instead of a `String` Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You Have Two Tables , You Can Compare Like Below

```
For x As Short = 0 To DT2.Rows.Count - 1
    If DT1.Select("In_Date='" & DT2.Rows(x)("In_Date") & "'").Length >=1 Then 
    '' Existing 
     Else
     '' Not Existing
   End If
Next
```